# how to get the name of a JMenu when a JMenuItem is clicked

Tags: java, exception, jmenu, jmenuitem

How would one get the name of the JMenu holding a clicked JMenuItem? I tried doing this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    JMenu menuthing = (JMenu)(arg0.getSource());
    String menuString =  menuthing.getText();
    JMenuItem source = (JMenuItem)(arg0.getSource());
    String colorType = source.getText();
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JMenuItem cannot be cast to javax.swing.JMenu
```

So is there a way to cast to JMenu, or some other way to determine the name?
Thanks.

Comment: *"How would one get the name of the JMenu holding a clicked JMenuItem?"*  A better question would be that sentence, but swapping 'How' for 'Why'.

Comment: +1 with @AndrewThompson here. Judging from the code that you've posted, I couldn't find a reason as to why you would really need to get hold of the JMenu. Would you want to elaborate?

Comment: I am writing a program where a set of boxes can have an 'alive' or 'dead' state (For those of you who aren't familiar with Conway's Game of Life. I want one menu to set the color of the alive position, and a menu to set the color of the dead position. That's why I need the name of the menu, to distinguish between the Alive menu and the Dead menu

Comment: I'd tend to use a `JComponent` for the cells, and add a `MouseListener` to change the state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest adding a `MenuListener` to your `JMenu` and add your code in `public void menuSelected(javax.swing.event.MenuEvent evt)`.

Since this is a `MenuEvent`, the `getSource()` method will return the `JMenu` object

If you want to get it from your `ActionEvent`, try something like this:

```
JPopupMenu menu = (JPopupMenu) ((JMenuItem) evt.getSource()).getParent();
JMenu actMenu = menu.getInvoker();
```

Comment: so to get the source, you would say evt.getSource()?

Comment: @Jeeter: yip! that is what you need to do :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of casting to a JMenu just cast to JMenuItem. Then get the JMenu from it.

```
JMenuItem jmi = (JMenuItem) arg0.getSource();
JPopupMenu jpm = (JPopupMenu) jmi.getParent();
JMenu menu = (JMenu) jpm.getInvoker();
```

Comment: Yip! I agree (and +1 for that). But that its, IF you really have to get it from an `ActionEvent`. But as @andrewthomson pointed out, i'm still unsure as to why the OP wants to get the name of the `JMenu` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the JMenuItems are the children of JMenu, you may still do it with ActionEvent:

```
JPopupMenupopup = new JPopupMenu();
popup.setName("popup");
```

....

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem source = (JMenuItem)(e.getSource());
    try{
        JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem) e.getSource(); 
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = (JPopupMenu) menuItem.getParent(); 
        Component invoker = popupMenu.getInvoker();      
        JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu) invoker.getParent();
        System.out.println("NAME OF JMENU: "+popup.getName());

        //If you need the selection of cell(s)
        JTable table = (JTable)popup.getInvoker();
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
        System.out.println("Selected cell: "+row+"-"+col);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```